# Can I name my website with more than 3 w's at the start?

Tags: web, dns

I just happened to come across this website http://wwwwwwwwwwwwww.allblacks.com/ which has 14 w's to it at the start. How is this possible?

Comment: This isn't a programming related question, so it is actually off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `www` is simply a convention.

You can set up any reasonable `<subdomain>.domain.com` by specifying an appropriate `A` or `AAAA`-record with your DNS-provider.

How this is done exactly depends on your DNS provider.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a domain name, so 14 w's is just as valid as www or another other domain component (eg ftp.example.com, mail.example.com, my-machine-is-great.example.com).